# Dentist screwed me on a bill. Do I have any options?

Tags: health-insurance, billing

A while ago I switched dentists. Despite reading a bunch of research about how the #1 predictor of high dental bills is switching dentists, my dentist proposed a "deep cleaning" and said my dental insurance would cover the majority of the bill.

Well it turns out after trying 2 types of health insurance, neither covers this cleaning and my new dentist just stuck me with a $900 bill, on top of what I already paid for the cleaning.

Do I have any recourse here? Alternatively, are there any tactics I can try to make the dentist forgive the bill? How flexible are dentists on this front?

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best place to ask this but I don't know where else to seek advice. If there is a better place then let me know where to ask.

Comment: You might have recourse, but it sure would have helped if you had had those exchanges by email, or at least memo'ed them by email, dated before the procedure, and referencing specific costs and insurance plan. You can certainly try disputing the bill.

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately you don't. Next time you will know not to agree to any dental procedure without having a quote from your insurance provider. Decent dentists will call up the insurance and get that quote pre-approved for you, and if your dentist doesn't do that - switch (again...).

All you can do now is just tell everyone and everywhere (including yelp) how disappointed you are with this dentist. Make sure to not say anything that is not factually correct though, as you can get sued.

Comment: The only medical bill that should ever come as a surprise is from an emergency room visit/operation. Routine doctor/dentist etc, never.

Comment: +1 You can also ask your medical/dental provider what procedure code they will use to bill, and then in most cases your insurer will be able to confirm if the procedure is covered, and how much they will cover (important if out-of-network). I was able to use this approach to make sure I'd be covered for a recent dental procedure.

Answer (score -1):

The dental office probably did try to get an accurate quote from your insurance, it is in THEIR best interest to do so as it will minimize their account's receivable workload. Insurance rep's are trained to be as deceptive and misleading as possible, bonusing and getting rewarded for DENYING claims. Even if they submitted a pre-authorization for treatment stating that your insurance will pay, they (your insurance) have the right to deny the claim upon dental consultant review. So you don't have any recourse unfortunately. My best advice would be to make sure you are following good home care instructions, getting regular cleanings and dental examinations so as to minimize future need for extensive treatment. Do careful research about your insurance plans, what are the provisions and exclusions and educate yourself on how the plan works. The amount of information will be dizying, but again this is because insurance needs to be as confusing as possible, in order to profit.

Comment: I don't see why this answer is getting down-voted.  There are three perspectives at play in this scenario: the consumer, the insurance agent, and the dentist.  Taking the dentist's perspective into account (as this answer attempts) vs only looking at the consumer / insurance agent's perspective, can be useful.  I'm certain many people have experienced (as I have also) insurance agencies behaving disreputably and denying legitimate claims based on technicalities.  The administrative overhead to prevent such errors can be burdensome to a small business owner.